# Alivepdf insert link inside a multicell?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, alivepdf

I'm working to a project in flex.
How can I insert a link inside a text of a multicell with alivepdf?

```
myPDF.addMultiCell(120,6,"Vedi su www.google.com",1,"J",0);
```

How can I make clickable www.google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code -

```
myPDF.addLink ( 120, 6, 60, 16, new HTTPLink ("http://www.google.com") );
```

Comment: This code will work only if I know in which position I should put the link. But I nedd a way to dynamically generate text with lik inside, so I need probably to modify the addMulticell function to make this possible... don't know if there is a better way...